# Track Actual Approver of Approval Process - Process Builder /Flow

Tags: case, approval-process, flow, process-builder

I have an Approval Process on Case object. I would like to track the name of the Actual Approver on a custom field 'Actual Approver Name' once a record has been Approved. Any ideas on how to carry out this using Process Builder /Flow? I do not want to use a trigger for this if I can avoid doing so.

Comment: Would it not just be a case of updating the lookup with the current users Id, with the assumption that you know what your criteria is (presumably something like status = approved).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create field updates for each step's approval action. In field update, update your custom field 'Actual Approver Name' with logged in user's Name. I think it will work as expected.

Comment: To add to this, I have created a text field that stamps the id of the approver to a field 'Approver ID Stamp'. Then using this field to update the lookup. Thanks for your help.